# Can't parse some JSON into a JsonArray using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to get the values from a JSON response. I got everything to work, except extracting an array from the following string:

```
{"o":"1.18988","h":"1.18993","l":"1.18963","c":"1.18993"}
```

I know GSON is trying to parse it because I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: {"o":"1.18988","h":"1.18993","l":"1.18963","c":"1.18993"}
```

I am using the following code to attempt to parse it:

```
final JsonElement midElement = obj.get("mid");
        final JsonArray midArray = midElement.getAsJsonArray();
        for(Object rate : midArray){
            final JsonObject rateObj = (JsonObject)rate;
            final JsonElement openElement = rateObj.get("o");
            open = openElement.getAsFloat();

            final JsonElement highElement = rateObj.get("h");
            high = highElement.getAsFloat();

            final JsonElement lowElement = rateObj.get("l");
            low = lowElement.getAsFloat();

            final JsonElement closeElement = rateObj.get("c");
            close = closeElement.getAsFloat();
        }
```

Comment: I think I answered it yesterday itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587719/json-object-cannot-be-converted-to-json-array/46587951#46587951

Comment: Json array should be enclosed in brackets?
 {["o":"1.18988","h":"1.18993","l":"1.18963","c":"1.18993"]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it doesn't look like a valid JSON array. It should look like this

```
[{"o":"1.18988","h":"1.18993","l":"1.18963","c":"1.18993"}]
```

Try this following code to parse it in JSON format.

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("mid");
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {             
         jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("o");
    }
```

Then convert it your preferred data form.